# Restore rep if downvoted post removed?

Tags: discussion, questions

Currently if you downvote a post and it is removed your lost reputation point is not restored. Wouldn't it make sense to restore lost reputation if you downvote on a post that is subsequently removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll gain the reputation back when your reputation is recalculated.  You can trigger a reputation recalc if you scroll all the way to the bottom of your [Reputation Report](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: When does it happen?

Comment: @Charlie: Looking for the link now.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I removed posts which was not supposed to do - if I knew that it would automatically ban you.. (I removed my post because I wanted to reask them, and then suddenly I could't ask anymore questions. Could you perhaps help me to lift my ban?